# How can I get my meshes to work with Bullet Physics?

Tags: opengl, c++, blender, bullet-physics

The problem is that I'm trying to use my meshes with Bullet Physics for the collision part of my game.

When I attempted doing this method with my GLM(model loading library by nate robins) model, I get a segmentation fault in the debug, so I figured that it doesnt like the coordinate variables of the model.

If i use blender to export my model as a collision file, what type of file should I use?

I have heard of a .bullet exporter, but i dont know hot to integrate this python script into my Blender 2.5 program.

Comment: 'bullet physics' are also called 'external ballistics' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ballistics

Comment: Heh. I think he's referring to the Bullet Physics engine http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot that part, its the Bullet Physics engine

Comment: I am suspicious that the bullet api is being used improperly, post code and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If it's segfaulting there's a bug in the library. Open a bug report and send them a reproducible test case.

Comment: so theres a bug in the bullet physics library? odd....

Comment: Based on what you've said there's a bug in the bullet physics engine. It's possible that one of us is misinterpreting something and the bug is actually in the model loading library. Either way, something is segfaulting rather than detecting an error and handling it gracefully. Not good in release mode (although I'm sure some game devs would argue that speed is more important); unacceptable in debug mode.

Comment: alright, hmm...i guess ill try another way.. but about the .bullet export thing, is that possible? also my current Blender version is 2.57(im not ultimately used to the interface, yet)

Comment: I never got the hang of the Blender interface. Sorry, can't help there.

Comment: alright, well i got the .bullet file exported, now im wondering how i would use it in my c++ game via bullet?